# sed backreferences returning their numerical index rather than their value

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Weird problem here that I don't seem to see repeated anywhere else, so posting here.  Thanks in advance.

I have the following multiline sed code that is printing further sed and copy commands into a script (yep, using a script to insert code into a script).  The code looks like this:

```
sed -i -r '/(rpub )([$][a-zA-Z0-9])/i\  
sed -i '\''/#PBS -N/d'\'' \1\
cp \1 '"$filevariable"'' $masterscript
```

which is supposed to do the following:

1.) Open the master script
2.) Navigate to each instance of rpub $[a-zA-Z0-9] in the script
3.) Insert the second line (sed) and third line (cp) as lines before the rpub instance, using \1 as a backreference of the matched $[a-zA-Z0-9] from step 1.

This works great; all lines print well enough in relation to each other. However, all of my \1 references are appearing explicitly, minus their backslashes.  So all of my \1's are appearing as 1.

I know my pattern match specifications are working correctly, as they nail all instances of rpub $[a-zA-Z0-9] well enough, but I guess I'm just not understanding the use of backreferences.  Anyone see what is going on here?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Special thanks to Ed Morton below, implemented the following, which gets me 99% closer, but I still can't close the gap with unexpected behavior:

```
awk -v fv="$filevariable" '
match($0, /rpub( [$][[:alnum:]])/, a)
{
print "sed -i '\''/#PBS -N/d'\''", a[1]
}
1' "$masterscript" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$masterscript"
```

Note: I removed one of the multiline print statements, as it isn't important here.  But, as I said, though this gets me much closer I am still having an issue where the printed lines appear between every line in the masterscript; it is as if the matching function is considering every line to be a match.  This is my fault, as I should probably have specified that I'd like the following to occur:

```
stuff here
stuff here
rpub $name
stuff here
rpub $othername
stuff here
```

would become:

```
stuff here
stuff here
inserted line $name
rpub $name
stuff here
insertedline $othername
rpub $othername
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Back references works in the RHS of the substitutions: `s/a\(.*\)b/\1/`

Comment: Welcome to sed debugging hell :-). Look, sed is for simple substitutions in individual lines. It's not for doing anything on multiple lines and it's not for writing multi-line scripts - just use awk for those cases, it's what it was invented to do. If you post another question explaining what you're trying to do (rather than how you're trying to do it) with sample input and expected output we could help you.

Comment: have you tried with `$1`?

Comment: @Ed, yeah, this is frustrating.  I've long felt that I've been using sed as a hammer when I should be using a screwdriver.  I've never before spent literal days trying to understand a few lines of code...

Comment: No exaggeration: if you are using any sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool. All those other arcane sed constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. People just use them now for the challenge of seeing if they can wrap their mind around it, like solving a puzzle, but they'd never produce a better (clearer, more portable, etc.) real solution than an awk script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It LOOKS like what you're trying to do could be written simply in awk as:

```
awk -i inplace -v fv="$filevariable" '
match($0,/rpub ([$][[:alnum:]])/,a) {
    print "sed -i \"/#PBS -N/d\", a[1]
    print "cp", a[1], fv
}
1' "$masterscript"
```

but without sample input and expected output it's just a guess.

The above uses GNU awk for inplace editing and the 3rd arg for match().

Comment: Ah this looks much more concise and understandable, but I can't get this to work either; it bites back saying that I'm not using gawk properly.  Incidentally, my script won't allow me to indent those print lines, which indicates I might be formatting this wrong?

Comment: Ah I see what's happening; the platform I'm on doesn't support the -i flag.  Old version of gawk maybe?

Comment: either older gawk or not gawk. Just use your own tmp file `awk '..' file > tmp && mv tmp file`, no big deal either way. Not sure what you mean by "my script won't allow me to indent those print lines".

Comment: Ed, thanks again.  I created a clarification edit above.  You brought me 99% of the way there, but the match seems to be getting triggered for every line.  No matter what regex I place in there, it seems to print my requested lines in between every line in the masterscript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, got it.  Added an edit to your solution.  Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a backreference to work the regular expression for it should be enclosed in parentheses, your second line is a second invocation of sed, nothing is saved from the first line.